# Where are gem installs coming from?

Tags: ruby, oauth, rubygems

I am wondering, while I'm sifting through samples, how I locate the source library when installing gems. For example, I have

```
require 'oauth2'
```

and to install, I run

```
gem install oauth2
```

What repository is pulled from for gem installs? I want to use reflection to reverse engineer some of the calls in the samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `gem` pulls from [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org), the main gem repository, but you can install from anywhere if you give it a URL or use the `--source` option to specify an alternate source. Some prefer to use private gem hosting for their dependencies.

Why not use a [`Gemfile`](https://bundler.io) to manage your dependencies? It makes it a lot more clear:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'

gem 'oauth2'
```

Then you install:

```
bundle install
```

Then you can see where it got installed:

```
bundle show oauth2
```

From there you can look at the source. You can also look at the [gem listing page for `oauth2`](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth2) where links to documentation and source are provided.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few useful options for looking at source code for ruby gems.
As @tadman has mentioned you generally can expect the default gem source to be hosted at https://rubygems.org and using [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) is also highly recommended.

In many cases the open source code will be hosted on https://github.com. I tend to prefer to fork the gem source and download my fork locally where I can analyze it in my editor without fear of accidentally breaking anything since your forked repo will contain the full git history/repo etc.

If you're new to ruby, I would highly recommend you use a ruby version manager, i.e. [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)  or perhaps [RBENV](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), although I tend to find RVM a bit simpler and less problematic.

My other personal favorite ruby code hacking/inspecting tool is [PRY](https://github.com/pry/pry)